# InternalSubStringWithChecks Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

We're getting this InternalSubStringWithChecks exception with our application's healthMonitoring.

This exception is like the [Padding is invalid](http://forums.asp.net/t/1019434.aspx) and cannot be removed exception where it's being recorded and we're getting a notification email but the end user is unaware that an actual error has happened. Though we don't want our event log filled up with this rubbish!

The stack trace is:

```
Event message: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length
   at System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean fAlwaysCopy)
   at System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I can't find any useful info on what causes this and how to fix it via Google. Has anyone else encountered/fixed this?

Comment: when does this occur in the asp.net page lifecycle?

Comment: @mohlsen - We don't know, all we've got is this stack trace to work off.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the Substring() method with incorrect arguments. For example:

```
string a = "test";

a.Substring(0,100)
```

will throw an exception.

Comment: See the stack trace provided, he didn't call `Substring()`

Comment: @Fedor, he did. You can see the InternalSubStringWithChecks which is used by the Substring() function.

Comment: @Skami Yeah, you're right. I had the similar problem and it turned out that, IIRC, ASP.NET internally called `Substring()` during page load. Unfortunately I can't remember what was the cause of this error but I've fixed it somehow.